# Filtering EVE REST API

Tags: python, eve

How to use OR/AND filter (mongoDB) with WHERE in url request?

`example.com/stats?where={"id":"1fd08077bd"}` - works OK

But I also need to filter by `{"_created":{"$gte":"Thu, 14 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT"}}`.

I tried `&and`

```
example.com/stats?where={"id":"1fd08077bd"}&and{"_created":{"$gte":"Thu, 14 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT"}}
```

But that was in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
example.com/stats?where={"$and":[{"_created":{"$gte":"Thu, 14 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT"}},{"id":"1fd08077bd"}]}
```

`$and` should be part of your `where` filter. Mind the date format. Should be the same used in your eve app.

Comment: Nice! You can mark the answer as correct if so, to help others too.